# How does one find and copy files of the same extension, in different directories, to a single directory in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

So,  How Do I find and copy all files,

```
*.a
```

that are in,

```
 ~/DIR{1,2,3,...}
```

to

```
 ~/tmp/foo?
```

Answer (score 6):

Assumed you meant recursively copy everything of type .a from some source location.
Haven't verified yet, but this should do that.

```
find <root-of-search> -type f -name '*.a' -exec cp {} /tmp/foo \;
```

replace  with the top of wherever you want to search from. You might have to throw quotes around *.a, and you might have to replace escape the ending semicolon by putting it in single quotes rather than back-slashing it.

Comment: $ find . -type f -name *.mkv -exec cp {} ../disk0/public/foo
find: paths must precede expression: foo.mkv

Comment: might be helpful to see if 'find' is working as intended; if you replace everything to the right of -exec with ls -l {} \; it should just list the files it's identified.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't read your post correctly.  I did what you said and it seems to be working...is working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a bash shell:

```
cp ~/DIR*/*.a ~/tmp/foo
```

Comment: This seems to work for me on Mac OSX. I did the same command in bash and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~/DIR{1,2,...} -name *.a print0 | xargs -i -0 cp '{}' ~/tmp/foo
```